# Django Haystack autocomplete does not work as expected

Tags: django, elasticsearch, autocomplete, django-haystack

Django==1.8.13, elasticsearch==1.7.1

I am implementing the autocomplete on the name field.

```
sqs = sqs.autocomplete(name=query)
```

search index for name:

```
name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name', boost=1.2)
```

no ordering is done on the queryset.

Search query : 'font'

Result:

-> Great fonts

-> some other value

-> Font Awesome

Expected result:

-> Font Awesome

-> xxxx (other values)

-> xxxx (other values)

---

Why doesn't "Font Awesome" come first in the list?

If I use NgramField instead of CharField, the value bumps up to 2nd position. But still its not correct as the value with word starting with query should come first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `CharField` with `sqs.autocomplete()`. From the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.0/autocomplete.html).

> You have two choices: `NgramField` and `EdgeNgramField`. Though very
>   similar, the choice of field is somewhat important.
>
> - If you’re working with standard text, `EdgeNgramField` tokenizes on whitespace. This prevents incorrect matches when part of two different
>     words are mashed together as one n-gram. This is what most users
>     should use.
> - If you’re working with Asian languages or want to be able to autocomplete across word boundaries, `NgramField` should be what you
>     use.

Either you need to change your `name` index field to an `EdgeNgramField` or (if you are using `name` elsewhere) create a separate field that is used for autocomplete searches, e.g.:

```
autocomplete_name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name')
```

Then query with:

```
sqs = sqs.autocomplete(autocomplete_name=query)
```

This should give you the expected results.

Comment: using EdgeNgramField results the value in 3rd position.